# Use the modified admin template only for one Image app

Tags: django, django-templates

**Django 3.0.6**

For one model I need a modified admin site template.

Namely, I want to modify this template:

```
admin/includes/fieldset.html
```

I have copied the fieldset.html from Django package directory and placed it like this:

```
/my_project/image/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html
```

Here image is my application. It is this application that needs a modified admin template.

The problem is that all other models also get this template. And the used template filters don't receive necessary params and explode.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories

Well, I got confused and fail to organize the necessary directories structure.

How can I use the modified template only for one Image app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, [only the following templates can be overridden per-app or per-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model):

- `actions.html`
- `app_index.html`
- `change_form.html`
- `change_form_object_tools.html`
- `change_list.html`
- `change_list_object_tools.html`
- `change_list_results.html`
- `date_hierarchy.html`
- `delete_confirmation.html`
- `object_history.html`
- `pagination.html`
- `popup_response.html`
- `prepopulated_fields_js.html`
- `search_form.html`
- `submit_line.html`

`fieldset.html` isn't in there, so you'll need to see if the including template(s) is in this list, and if it is, replace *this* template and use it to include your own version of `fieldset.html`.

Also, your location (slightly modified since can't override included templates per-app): `/my_project/image/templates/admin/template.html` isn't quite right. This will overwrite that template for *every* app. To do it per-app, you need a further subdirectory under admin:

```
/my_project/image/templates/admin/image/template.html
```

The reason for this is that templates don't really care about which app they're in, so the fact that the template lives in your `image` app doesn't mean anything to Django, the convention of putting them in your app's sub-directory is solely to avoid overriding templates that you don't intend to.